# PHP nusoap (webservice) keep class alive + C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I'm trying to keep the same class alive in the various functions. This works perfectly with PHP, but when I use the same functions in C# it does not work as expected.

My index.php file consists in this:

```
<?php 
    require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php'); 
    require_once('libs/webservice.php');

    $web    = new webservice(); // this is a class

    function login($user_email, $user_password){
        global $web;
        return json_encode($web->login($user_email, $user_password));
    }

    function getClients(){
        global $web;
        return json_encode($web->getClients());
    }

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server = new soap_server();
    $server->register("login");
    $server->register("getClients");
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

If I add, after the `$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);` the following PHP code just for testing:

```
echo login("testing@hotmail.com", "testing"); // returns TRUE > which is correct
echo getClients(); // returns TRUE > which is correct
```

It works great. The class holds the `user_id` which is going to be used in other functions.
Now, the class **webservice** has the following:

```
class webservice{

    private $user;
    private $user_id;

    public function __construct(){
        require_once("../libs/user.php");
        $this->user     = new users();
    }

    public function login($email, $password){
        $results = $this->user->logIn($email, sha1($password));

        if($results['id'] == null){
            return json_encode(array("message" => false));
        }

        $this->user_id  = $results['id']; // holds the user id for further functions needs

        return json_encode(array("message" => true));
    }

    public function getClients(){
        if($this->user_id == null){
            return json_encode(array("message" => false));
        }

        return json_encode(array("message" => true));
    }
}
?>
```

As I said, in PHP this works great. However, when I'm using this webservice in C#, I cannot retrieve the result TRUE from `getclients()` function due to the `user_id` is equal to null. **It does not hold** the `user_id` once logged in.

```
WebReference.myWebservice webS = new WebReference.myWebservice();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JObject login = JObject.Parse(webS.login("testing@hotmail.com", "testing"));
    MessageBox.Show(login["message"].ToString()); // returns TRUE

    JObject clients = JObject.Parse(webS.getClients());
    MessageBox.Show(clients["message"].ToString()); // returns FALSE
}
```

I know that the problem is on **index.php** page, but how can I implement what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call your webservice your script will create a new instance of `class webservice` in php. That means that your `$user_id` will not hold the userid of your last request.

You should return a hash (session) and the userid by your login function. Store the hash and the userid in c#. After that your hash and userid should be part of every request. Validate it inside your webservice class and return the results of the users request.

I hope you could follow my instructions.

Maybe take a look into twitters rest service api:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

I like the way they did it. You send an authentication request and twitter returns a hash called bearer. After that every request includes an Authorization header with the value of the bearer.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it..but I was hopping to implement by my way.
But if no one has any clue if this is possible or not, I'll go for that way.

Comment: The problem is that your instance is gone when the request is finished. That is the way how a http request works. If you want to do it like this you need to build a socket server with php (a php script that runs in a endless loop). But i think this is not the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes..it isn't the simplest solution. Well, thank you. I'll go for what your solution.